# Pop up menu in Jquery mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile, menu, popup

I am trying to create pop up menu using Jquery mobile, by clicking the button it should pop up menu options without changing the page, similar to select menu of jquery mobile.Is there any way to do that in JQM?

Thanks...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is [Popup widget](http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.0/docs/widgets/popup/)  what i needed. It may help someone in future.